# shopify Title instead of product id. API Python

Tags: python, api, shopify

I would like to find all the titles in my shopify store. I found this piece of code which give me the product id.

```
xxx = shopify.Product.find(limit=50, page=1)
```

What I am looking for is the title.........

**I tried**

```
xxx = shopify.Product.title(limit=50, page=1)
xxx = shopify.Product.title(limit=50, page=1).title()
xxx = shopify.title(limit=50, page=1)
xxx = title(limit=50, page=1)
```

What I want to see on the output window.

```
'This is the title of the product' <- this is what I want to extract
```

What I get now is

```
product(322940174383) <- bad I want the title not product id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I edited my answer because I misunderstood your question.
You have to iterate over your entire product list, you can do something like this:

```
p_count = shopify.Product.count()
p_max_pages = int(p_count / 250) + 1
titles = []
for page in range(1, p_max_pages + 1):
    products = shopify.Product.find(page=page, limit=250)
    for product in products:
        titles.append(product.title)
```

In the product object in the loop you can find all the properties listed in the [Shopify Documentation](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/product)

OLD ANSWER

If you want to get products by title you should use

```
shopify.Product.find(title="My Product")
```

This returns the list of products that contains the string "My Product"

Comment: I want the api  to find all the titles in the inventory. Not  just one. Also this still just gives me the product id number which is not what I want I want the title of the product

Comment: @benolsen I edited my answer, I misunderstood what you are trying to achieve.